# multi dimension session array

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array, increment

I am using a form that is pulling data from two MySQL databases into a single dynamic page. When a user clicks add to cart I want to store that data in a multi dimensional session array to call up later when they click view cart. I am wondering how to auto increment the subset identifier(array key?) of the item when a new item is added from the add to cart form. This is what I have so far:

```
$newitem = array ($row_getimages['icon'],$row_getimages['title'],$row_getshoppingcart['medium'],$row_getshoppingcart['size'],$row_getshoppingcart['price'],$row_getshoppingcart['shipping']);


session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['item'][1]))
$_SESSION['item'][1] = $_SESSION['item'][1]+ 1;
else
$_SESSION['item'][1] = 1;
```

Also any help for calling out the data later would be appreciated. As a user may have 1 or 20 items stored in the session I am not sure how to make sure all items would be echoed no matter how many they have added.

This is my first time at a multi dimensional array and sessions. Obviously because the image page is dynamic and purchase price is based on several factors, just using a MySQL database of available items as I have in the past is out of the question.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "subset identifier"? Do you mean the array key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newitem = array ('id' => $row_getshoppingcart['id'] , 'icon' => $row_getimages['icon'],'title' => $row_getimages['title'],'medium' => $row_getshoppingcart['medium'],'size' => $row_getshoppingcart['size'],'price' => $row_getshoppingcart['price'],'shipping' => $row_getshoppingcart['shipping']);


session_start();

$_SESSION['item'][] = $newitem;
```

That is all you have to do, if I understand your system correctly.

**UPDATE**

I updated the `$newitem` array to include array keys. You can reference the new item info with arrays like this:

> $_SESSION['item'][(num)]['id']

Or you can loop through the results like this:

```
foreach ( $_SESSION['item'] AS $item ) 
{  
 echo 'id: ' . $item['id'] . '<br />'; 
 echo 'title: ' . $item['title'];  
 // and so on 
}
```

Comment: That will not overwrite the first item added when a second is added?

Comment: It will not. It will auto-increment the array key. The first will be `$_SESSION['item'][0]`, then `$_SESSION['item'][1]` and so on

Comment: The setup would be something like this: item - 1 - a,b,c,d,e,f then I would need to add item - 2 - a,b,c,d,e,f in addition to item 1.

Comment: Awesome, you have been a huge help. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I would recommend array keys for your item data array

Comment: Great idea. Any suggestion as to how I would call that data out later on for the view cart page? Since it will be auto increment for the key I will have no way to uniquely identify each one. Would this be something a loop until no data exists would work for?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not important for the numbers to be sequential, you can use:

```
$_SESSION['item'][] = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
```

Using `[]` will simply add a new element to the end of the array.

However, I would probably use a product ID for the key.

Comment: That is correct, though I would not use the product ID for the key. In a shopping cart, you want to know how many items are in it, so it should auto-increment. I would put the product ID in the item data array

Comment: @christopher I would think that the data would contain all that information (an array, an object, etc.), the simple string is just an example. Either way it is not that important, I just tend to use it like that...

Comment: the setup would be something like this: item 1, a,b,c,d,e,f then I would need to add item 2, a,b,c,d,e,f in addition to item 1.