# Illegal string offset in echo $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, offset

Recently I trying to study about how to add cart in php and MySQL. Until then I found this useful [website](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-shopping-cart-with-php-and-mysql--net-5144).

However there are a lot of error, that some of it I already know how to correct it.

But I can't understand what this Illegal string offset is about. The error is at line 64 in index.php which is as below.

This is the line 64 error

```
<p><?php echo $row['name'] ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?></p>
```

[Sample Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnaZZ.png)

```
<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){ 

    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN ("; 

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) { 
        $sql.=$id.","; 
    } 

    $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC"; 
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 

    ?> 
        <p><?php echo $row['name'] ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?></p> 
    <?php 

    } 
?>
```

Comment: `isset` returns TRUE on null or empty value. I prefer `!empty()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688071/multi-dimension-session-array

Answer (score 0):

try checking with this

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
   echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION['cart']);echo "</pre>";
}
```

Check weather `$_SESSION['cart']` is array or not.
Try this to also to check => `var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);`